# Time evolution of an electron in an homogeneous magnetic field: get rid of $S_y$ in the exponential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, hamiltonian

#### Context

We have a particle of spin $1/2$ and of magnetic moment $\vec{M} = \gamma\vec{S}$.

At time $t=0$, the state of the system is
$$
|\psi(t=0) \rangle = |+\rangle_z
$$

We let the system evolve under the influence of a magnetic field $B_0$ parallel to $Oy$.

We are asked to find the state of the system at time $t$.

#### Attempt

The energy of interaction between the $B$ field and the spin is
$$\hat{H} = E_m \equiv -\vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{B} = - \gamma \vec{S} \cdot B_0 \hat{y} = - \gamma B_0 y S_y = \omega_0 S_y$$

where $\gamma$ denotes the gyromagnetic ratio and $S_y$ is the spin operator in the $y$ direction.

We can write the time-dependance of $\psi$ by applying the time-evolution operator on $|\psi(t=0)\rangle$,
$$
\begin{align}
  |\psi(t)\rangle 
    &= e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\psi(t=0)\rangle \\
    &= e^{-i \omega_0 S_y t/\hbar}|+\rangle_z
\end{align}
$$

Now I would like to express $|+\rangle_z$ in the $\{|+\rangle_y, |-\rangle_y\}$ basis.

We can express $S_y$ in term of the Pauli matrix $\sigma_y$,
$$
S_y = \frac{\hbar}{2} \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i \\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}}_{\sigma_y}
$$

Finding the eigenvalues of $S_y$,
$$
det(S_y - \lambda I) = 0 \implies \lambda_{1,2} = \pm \frac{\hbar}{2}
$$

Finding the eigenvectors,
$$
(S_y - \lambda_{1,2}I)(\chi) = \vec{0}
$$

- $\lambda_1 = \hbar/2$
  $$
  \frac{\hbar}{2}
  \begin{pmatrix}-1 & -i \\ i & -1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\chi_{_+} \\ \chi_{_-}\end{pmatrix}
  = 
  \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
  \implies 
  \begin{cases}
  -\chi_{_+} - i\chi_{_-} = 0 \\ i\chi_{_+} - \chi_{_{-}} = 0
  \end{cases}
  $$

We find the normalised eigenvector
$$
\chi_{_+} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ i\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can write
$$
|+\rangle_y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle_z + i|-\rangle_z \right)
$$

- $\lambda_1 = -\hbar/2$
  $$
  \frac{\hbar}{2}
  \begin{pmatrix}1 & -i \\ i & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\chi_{_+} \\ \chi_{_-}\end{pmatrix}
  = 
  \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
  \implies 
  \begin{cases}
  \chi_{_+} - i\chi_{_-} = 0 \\ i\chi_{_+} + \chi_{_{-}} = 0
  \end{cases}
  $$

We find the normalised eigenvector
$$
\chi_{_-} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -i\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can write
\begin{equation}
|-\rangle_y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle_z - i|-\rangle_z \right)
\end{equation}

Inverting the $|+\rangle_y$ and $|-\rangle_y$ relations we get
$$
\begin{cases}
|+\rangle_z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle_y + i|-\rangle_y \right) \\
|-\rangle_z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle_y - i|-\rangle_y \right)
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore,
\begin{align}
|\psi(t)\rangle 
    &= e^{-i \omega_0 S_y t/\hbar}|+\rangle_z \\
    &= e^{-i \omega_0 S_y t/\hbar} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle_y + i|-\rangle_y \right)
\end{align}

Now my question is how can i get rid of $S_y$ knowing that $S_y =\frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i \\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}$, I mean in class we saw that
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-i \frac{\omega_0}{2} t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle_y + i|-\rangle_y \right)
$$
But I don't see how do we get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the basis of eigenstates of $S_y$, the matrix representation of $S_y$ is diagonal and of the form
\begin{align}
S_y\to \frac{\hbar}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
so that the exponential of $S_y$ is a diagonal matrix
\begin{align}
e^{-i \omega_0 t S_y/\hbar} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ i \end{array}\right)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c} e^{i\omega_0 t/2} \\ i e^{-i\omega_0 t/2}\end{array}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\omega_0 t/2} 
\vert +\rangle_y +\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-i\omega_0 t/2}\vert -\rangle_y\, .
\end{align}
This is all done in the basis of eigenstates of $S_y$.  There remains to convert to the eigenstates of $S_z$.